# Onclick condition

Tags: onclick, conditional-statements

and thanks to read me.
I have a question...
It's possible a condition in onclick event?

For the moment i have :

```
<button iconClass="dijitButtonIcon dijitButtonIconCsv" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" 
                onclick="protectDblClick(this);window.open('../plugin/IGE-XAO_CompositionReport/checkCompatibility.php?product1=' + dijit.byId('projectSelected3').get('value'),'theFrame');">
                    <?php echo i18n("createCSV");?>
                </button>
```

But, i want to create a condition..
if product1 is null, i want to display an error with a function named showError()

I haven't seen on internet a solution ...
Thanks for help ! :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and just setup a proper javascript block with event handlers. `onclick` is so limited (and dated).

Comment: and what in this case is product1? is that dijit.byId('projectSelected3').get('value') "?

Comment: for you second question, it's yes.
I know onclic is limited but i work on an old project...

Comment: Old projects are still compatible with modern code..